# Realm instance limit

Tags: java, android, realm

Recently I got this this exception.

```
Fatal Exception: io.realm.exceptions.RealmError: Unrecoverable error. Too many open files in /Users/cm/Realm/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_SharedRealm.cpp line 92
```

Is there an actual limit in how many realm instances can be open at any time? If so, is it possible to close any of them that are not accessible?

*Not accessible* as in such instance which does not have direct call to it and is ready to be collected by garbage collector.

Edit: We're using realm 2.1

Comment: How many Realm files do you have open?

Comment: Which version of Realm do you use? Realm Java v1.1.1 reduced the number of file descriptors used so I have curious to see if Realm is still using too many descriptors.

Comment: @geisshirt We're using realm 2.1 in that particular project.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce For our database we're only using 1 file. We have also tracked down that this is related to a recursive bug in our project, but the question is still valid, isn't it?

Comment: Android/Linux has an upper limit on how many file descriptors (a process can use. That includes also network connections (sockets). So the question is if you have many open files and connections?

Comment: I think you can run into this issue only if you're opening the same Realm file from ~100+ threads at the same time and you don't close the instance.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce That's fair. But question does stand how do you close Realm instances that you don't have access to or even that were opened in now dead threads?

Comment: `But question does stand how do you close Realm instances that you don't have access to or even that were opened in now dead threads?` it is your responsibility to make sure that doesn't happen. If you follow the docs, this doesn't happen. https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#closing-realm-instances

Comment: @EpicPandaForce According to that document should I close the realm objects always inside of the `finally` block? Thanks.

Comment: On background threads, yes. Can't really use finally for UI thread Realm.